# Unable to Reverse Engineer (DBRE) in Spring Roo

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, spring-roo

I am attempting reverse engineer a MSSQL Database but I am unable to even show any addons. When I do attempt to perform a reverse engineer or introspect on the database I receieve the following error.

**Spring Roo automatic add-on discovery service currently unavailable
JDBC driver not available for 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver'**

When I attempt to do an addon search I recieve the following message

**Spring Roo automatic add-on discovery service currently unavailable**

I get these messages both inside STS roo shell and the command prompt roo shell. I have been having trouble for sometime and tried working with the proxy but no luck, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This solved the JDBC driver not available for 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver' problem. As mentioned here http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?127946-Unable-to-find-the-JTDS-driver

1. Check the version of jtds in pom.xml.
2. Locate the jar in repository OR download new jar from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/.
3. In Roo console type 
   osgi start --url file:///[path-to-jar-file]/jtds-1.2.4.jar